# How to migrate from monoliths/microservices to Faas?

Tags: microservices, migrating, faas

I'm currently studying these concepts and I wondered how this could be done.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please post, what's been analyzed so far

Answer (score 1):

That's a very generic question so I can't talk about any design concept. In the more technical side you can add an API gateway in front of the exiting solution and the when you create a new function route to that instead of the existing system. This is known as [strangler/strangler fig pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/strangler-fig)